# Sefardi praying schacharit with Ashkenazim

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, ashkenazi, tzibur-community, shacharis-morning-prayer, tachanun

1. What should a sefardi do during tachanun when praying with ashkenazim?
   They don't say veyavor and when they sit they put their head on their arm.
   What about on Mondays/Thursdays where Sefardim sit first then stand up, but Ashkenazim stand and then sit down at the end?
2. Also should/can a sefardi praying with ashkenazim skip tefilah ledavid, bet yaakaov shir hamalot and ketoret?

Comment: depends on the situation and what siddur you always used. Give more detail.

Comment: Rivevos Ephraim 7:47:1 http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1083&pgnum=46

Comment: Dovid, what difference does it make which siddur you use? Do you mean nusach?

Comment: My general understanding of any "mixed" situation such as this (e.g. Nusach Sfard person in Nusach Ashkenaz shul) is that things said "privately" are done in your own regular Nusach, wheeras public items such as Kedusha you follow the nusach of the shul you're in. I don't know how Tachanun fits into this, but I think it's the "private" categpry, although I understand that you need a minyan to say 13 Middot.

Comment: @sam, please provide a translation as an answer.

Comment: I meant nusach sorry

Comment: @DanF: Rav Ovadia Yosef and his sons definitely don't paskin that way. See my answer, and the chapters I've cited in all of Rav Ovadia and his sons' relevant works.

Answer (score 3):

## Tachanun

According to Halacha Berurah 131:2, a Sepharadi davening with Ashkenazim needs to say vidui, and the 13 midot. Apparently, he should say the 13 midot with ta'amim (as he would if he were davening alone - 131:9).

If it's a Monday or Thursday, he should just say the first instance of the 13 midot. In the other times it appears in the extended tachanun, he should only say from "El melech yoshev" thru "katuv b'toratach". (Halacha Berurah 131:9)

I would guess that since it's rather dangerous to say Psalm 25 in tachanun while falling on your face (if you can't have proper kavvanah), you should not fall on your face even in an Ashkanzi shul where everyone else is. (See Halacha Berurah 131:17)

## Aleinu

According to Halacha Berurah 132:15, you should daven as you normally would, but bow when the Ashkenazim are bowing. In practice, I've found that you'll be interrupted by kaddish in a couple of places where you wouldn't normally be interrupted in a Sepharadi shul.